# Cannot validate null values for integer input in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, integer, data-annotations

How can I validate Score property below with DataAnnotations in ASP.NET MVC?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required field")]
public int Score { get; set; }
```

I can validate this field by using @Html.TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Score, new { name = "Score", id = "Score", 
    @class = "form-control" , @Value = "" })
```

But cannot validate for integer input:

```
<input type="text" id="Score" name="Score" value="" >
<script>
    $("input[name='Score']").TouchSpin({
        verticalbuttons: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You manual code is not generating the necessary `data-val-* attributes for client side validation. And it shoould be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Score, new { @class = "form-control" }). NEVER attempt to set the `name` or `value` attributes (and using `name = "Score"` dos nothing anyway) and the helper is already creating `id="Score"`

Comment: Thanks for reply. What do you suggest to fix the problem? I use the integer input as for the second component and when it is empty I want to validate and display related error message. Any help please?

Comment: Why not use the `TextBoxFor()` method?

Comment: Integer Input type is much more pretty for entering grades :)

Comment: What do you mean? You property is `int`! `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Score)` will create the same html as you manual html except that it will also add the necessary `data-val-*` attributes for client side validation (as well as giving you correct 2-way model binding which you manual html wont)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can also use **@Html.TextBoxFor** as integer input by just adding the javascript below that element. Many thanks for clarifying me by showing this point of view. Regards...

Comment: Note also its better to use `$('#Score').TouchSpin({ ... });`

Comment: Ok, I will keep it mind. Many thanks for your help. On the other hand, I see that this problem is also seen for **Bootstrap typeahead** (autocomplete) when using Id for data value. Shall I also use @Html.TextBoxFor for **Bootstrap typeahead** (autocomplete)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124130/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-binary).

Answer (score -1):

Try to change property's type from int to int?

Comment: It is not nullable.